# How to bind Office web addin dynamically on demand from host application(asp.net website)

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-addins

For VSTO I have a provision to call it based on demand from my host application. Where as for web addin it is globally installed in server so it will be reflected if I open any word document. I want the addin to be activated programmatically from my host application(.Net/C# MVC). Please suggest how can I achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with Office Web Add-ins currently. Please go to [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) and search to see if this idea has been suggested. If it has, vote for it. If it hasn't, make the suggestion.

Comment: Rick-  To detect this I have a mechanism customized. But problem is closeContainer method is not working. To test closeContainerMethod I created a simple button and binding this method  `function closeWindow() {
  // Run a batch operation against the Word object model.
  Word.run(function (context) {
   Office.context.ui.closeContainer();
   
   // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
   return context.sync();
  })
   .catch(errorHandler);
 }` but it is telling closeContainer method not found

Comment: Please raise the problem with closeContainer on the repo for the Office JavaScript Library: [office.js new issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/new/choose).